# eval vs string.split when getting values from .env (environment variable)

Tags: python, config, eval, strsplit, .env

In Python project I have a list of values stored in a .env file as environment variables. I wonder if it is better to use eval or string.split to get the values.

1. eval

*.env*

```
ANIMALS=["Cat","Dog"]
```

*code.py*

```
animal_list=eval(os.getenv("ANIMALS"))
```

2. string.split

*.env*

```
ANIMALS=Cat,Dog
```

*code.py*

```
animal_list=os.getenv("ANIMALS").split(",")
```

Comment: Since eval introduces a potential security flaw, where one could replace the environment variable with harmful code, I would personally go with split, but this is an Opinion Based question, which is off topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: If you have a chance to avoid eval/exec, do it. There's also `json.loads()`.

Comment: You should be able to safely evaluate this with [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)